# Loft elevator for human

Tags: attic, electric-motor

Im thinking of implementing simple lift system to carry goods as well as a single person into the attic. 250Kg capacity electric hoist is good enough for this pupose but im concerned about safely aspect of this proposal.

Many youtube videos are showing this but none of them using it to transport a person.

Why not?

Comment: Probably the safety requirements they can get very complex. Both electrical and mechanical safety requirements, I have installed stair climbers and the inspectors really try to find something wrong. I am sure carting a person up and down would be worse. At the last mill I worked at we did have a "lift belt" it had platforms you stepped into and lifted you up, there was a safety cage around it as you went up so you couldn't fall off, it was installed in the late 40's but sure made life easier going to the 3rd level about 60' climb. It had been grandfathered but even it had safety.

Comment: Have you read the ASME A17.1 elevator codes lately?  Because your AHJ is going to read *any* manlift system as falling under that piece of Code...and it's a big 'un!

Comment: @EdBeal im living in south east asia. Im sure there will be some regulation in my country to govern this under machinery act. But since im doing in for personal use in my private home, i wont be having issues with authority and law.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel not sure about this codes. Its of usa?

Comment: @soosaisteven -- ah, sorry for assuming your location -- ASME A17.1 is what governs elevator installs in North America, but your local jurisdiction should have adopted a substantially equivalent-in-function document.  (If they haven't, it's still wise to follow a good Code on this front because there's an awful lot of wisdom packed into them.)

Comment: Unless your jurisdiction is really weird, life-safety equipment does not get a private-property or personal-use exemption.  The very fact that you are putting a human on it **places** it in jurisdiction.  Even if you think your jurisdiction is weird, even if some guy in an office will quietly pocket 600 baht to tell you what you want to hear -- when the gov't gets wind of you hurting someone, you will suddenly find *you were subject to code all along*.

Comment: @Harper im not suicidal. What im looking for is wheter or not this this can be diy-ed with safety aspects in place and at reasonable cost without having inspected by authority. Why i dont want this to be inspected is because, im sure the law requiers only certified and licienced builders to set up this machine.

Comment: Well, yes, if you **want to take the time** to get the code books, understand all the design factors, look at how others build elevators etc. , then it is humany possible for you to build an ultrasafe elevator.  Anyone can do anything if they apply unlimited amounts of willfulness.  However in reality 99.9% of people will get a disease called "get-er-done-itis" and cut corners by choosing to be ignorant about safety factors which, it turns out, actually do matter.

Comment: yes it can be done safely on the down-low, but nobody who's anyone will condone that, lest you blame them for something bad happening. I've ridden in dumb waiters. i've also broken one doing that. use a speed clutch or a worm drive or a hydralic system that doesn't crash to earth if the power goes out, has some accessible emergency stop features, and keeps limbs from shearing against the passageway.

Comment: @dandavis i got your points. Most electric hoist are using worm drives. I just need a safe carrier cage in which persons' limbs should be safe from pinched out. The up/down control of the system should be press&hold (deadman switch) and will under the control of the person who rides the elevator. This far, i see the system is safe enough. But what if the motor fail while im halfway into the levels? I cant' think what can be done to avoid such scenario.

Comment: you could use an uninterruptible power supply, like for a computer, to provide enough power to finish a trip or two...